# Different formatting on pretty tab on web logs after upgrading to segment/analytics-node

Tags: node.js, twilio, segment-analytics

Before, using **analytics-node 5.2.0**, in the "pretty" tab of the log viewer, a request is displayed as follows:

[image: analytics-node 5.2.0]

When upgrading to **@segment/analytics-node 2.0.0**, the same request is displayed as a curl command:

[image: @segment/analytics-node 2.0.0]

Why is this happening? Is there any way to show on pretty tab the requests in the same format as before with the new library?